# Codeigniter: Prefix string in select to all columns specified

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following select queries.

```
    $this->db->select("$order_table.user_id, $order_table.total_price,
                       $order_table.shipping, $order_table.tax, 
                       $order_table.filled, $order_table.shipped, 
                        $order_table.tracking");
    $this->db->select("$user_table.first_name as user_first_name, 
                       $user_table.last_name as user_last_name, 
                       $user_table.email as user_email");
    $this->db->select("$mailing_address_table.first_name as mailing_first_name, 
                       $mailing_address_table.last_name as mailing_last_name, 
                       $mailing_address_table.address as mailing_address, 
                       $mailing_address_table.address_2 as mailing_address_2, 
                       $mailing_address_table.city as mailing_city, 
                       $mailing_address_table.state as mailing_state, 
                       $mailing_address_table.zip_code as mailing_zip_code, 
                       $mailing_address_table.country as mailing_country");

    $this->db->select("$billing_address_table.first_name as billing_first_name, 
                       $billing_address_table.last_name as billing_last_name, 
                       $billing_address_table.address as billing_address, 
                       $billing_address_table.address_2 as billing_address_2, 
                       $billing_address_table.city as billing_city, 
                       $billing_address_table.state as billing_state,              
                       $billing_address_table.zip_code as billing_zip_code, 
                       $billing_address_table.country as billing_country");

    $this->db->join($user_table, 
                   "$user_table.id = $order_table.user_id", "left");
    $this->db->join($mailing_address_table, 
                   "$mailing_address_table.user_id = $user_table.id", "left");
    $this->db->join($billing_address_table, 
                   "$billing_address_table.user_id = $user_table.id", "left");
```

Is there anyway, I imagine using CONCAT, that I can prefix "billing_" to each column that I'm selecting in billing. I can't seem to figure this out when I'm not selecting everything, but rather just specific columns.

Id like each column I select from $user_table to be prefix with "user_", $mailing_table "mailing_" and so on.

**Note:**

1) I am not selecting all the fields from each column in these select queries, so I can't do SELECT * FROM...

2) I don't want to UPDATE the column names in the database, just for this specific SELECT use.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have done?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a shorthand for what I've done. Since, for instance in the billing select, all the column names have billing_ prefixed to them by hand and the field names are the names of the actual columns.

Comment: @RiggsFolly And thank you for the indent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can create to field list:

```
SET @SCHEMA = 'toimport';

SET @PREFIX = 'billing_';
SET @POSTFIX = 'address';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
 CONCAT(@SCHEMA,'.',@PREFIX,'.',@POSTFIX,'.',COLUMN_NAME,
 ' AS ',@PREFIX,COLUMN_NAME) SEPARATOR ',\n')
 FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMA AND TABLE_NAME = CONCAT( @PREFIX,  @POSTFIX );
```

The Result look likes:

```
toimport.billing_.address.id AS billing_id,
toimport.billing_.address.name AS billing_name,
toimport.billing_.address.street AS billing_street,
toimport.billing_.address.a1 AS billing_a1,
toimport.billing_.address.a2 AS billing_a2
```

Comment: wow, and good luck debugging that when used with 4+tables etc

Answer (score 0):

Here your Answer for more Tables:

The Query:

```
SET @SCHEMA = 'toimport';

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      @SCHEMA,'.',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', 1),'.',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', -1),'.',
      COLUMN_NAME, ' AS ',
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, '_', 1),'_',COLUMN_NAME
    ) SEPARATOR ',\n'
  )
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMA
  AND TABLE_NAME IN ('billing_address', 'email_post');
```

The Result is like:

```
toimport.billing.address.id AS billing_id,
toimport.billing.address.name AS billing_name,
toimport.billing.address.street AS billing_street,
toimport.billing.address.a1 AS billing_a1,
toimport.billing.address.a2 AS billing_a2,
toimport.email.post.id AS email_id,
toimport.email.post.name AS email_name,
toimport.email.post.street AS email_street,
toimport.email.post.a1 AS email_a1,
toimport.email.post.a2 AS email_a2
```